# C# Process.Start() Argument doesn't work properly

Tags: c#

I'm trying to silently install Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable using process.start() but have never got any luck. Please anyone help me.

I have the following code

```
string path = mypath;                          
startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = "/q:a /c:\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\\vcredist_x86.log\"";
startInfo.FileName = path + @"\vcredist_x86.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process exeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

the actual commandline argument is

/q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\vcredist_x86.log"

I got this command from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/23/715755.aspx

I verified this argument works perfect manually in cmd, but the code never works.

I also tried following code but had no luck as well

```
 startInfo.Arguments = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("/q:a /c:\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\\vcredist_x86.log\""));


 startInfo.Arguments = "/q:a /c:\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\\\\vcredist_x86.log\""
```

Please anyone let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Is this with an MSI of your own?

Comment: does your application have elevated permission?

Comment: No. there is no such an any custom msi. I downloaded the installer from MS website. It is ms c++ 2005 redistributable installer

Comment: @AppDeveloper No. There is no restriction of any permission. My test environment for this app is x86 windows xp. And it runs always as admin

Comment: How does your code fail to work? vcredist_x86.exe doesn't run? It runs with wrong argument? You may check the argument by [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or similar tools.

Comment: @LoveRight According to the my custom log, the process starts and gets finished immediately doing nothing. If I run this through the code without any argument, that works well but with UI prompts which I want to suppress. Thus, I clearly see this is about wrong argument. But the funny thing is that if I run it manually in command prompt with the argument, it works well without any UI prompts

Comment: what about `%temp%` instead of `temp%` ?

Comment: @joe Thanks for correcting me.It was typo. I just corrected my thread. In my actual code, that was %temp%, and it did not work. Thanks

Comment: Try to place an "@" before the argument string: `startInfo.Arguments = @"...";`. This disables escaping.

Comment: I replaced vcredist_x86.exe by gvim.exe and ran your code. Process Explorer shows that gvim.exe receives the correct argument. My guess is that vcredist_x86.exe will detect the parent process. Your program may output a bat file, which runs vcredist_x86.exe.

Comment: @LoveRight I solve this problem by taking out the log file going into %temp%. I used "/q:a /c:\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn" as process start info argument, and this working well. The previous argument was correct as well but It seems to be failing when the log file gets saved to %temp%. it may be because the location of %temp% is not in same WorkingDerectory. I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason.   Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the bandwidth to download these things to test, but, try this:

replace the 4 slashes in:

```
/l*v temp%\\\\vcredist_x86.log\""
```

with just 2 slashes:

```
/l*v temp%\\vcredist_x86.log\""
```

Comment: Ok no worries. Hope you get it sorted.